# How to use IntersectionObserver to properly continuously fetch data when initial render fits within client viewport?

Tags: javascript, viewport, infinite-scroll, intersection-observer

[A popular](https://github.com/ankeetmaini/react-infinite-scroll-component) infinite scroll react component has not been maintained for a few years now, so I put together something simple using IntersectionObserver.

```
const InfiniteScroll = (props: Props) => {
    const bottomRef = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
            if (entries[0].isIntersecting)
                props.next();
        });

        if (bottomRef.current)
            observer.observe(bottomRef.current);

        return () => {
            if (bottomRef.current)
                observer.unobserve(bottomRef.current);
        };
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
            {props.children}
            {props.hasMore && <div ref={bottomRef}></div>}
        </>
    )
}

export default InfiniteScroll;
```

When the div with ref `bottomRef` intersects the viewport the callback ensures `props.next()` is run and more data is fetched. And it works well enough *if the initial content is sufficiently large to scroll off the page*.

If the initial content already fits within the viewport then I see an initial "observer intersection" event and then nothing. Presumably because the IntersectionObserver already notified that the intersection happened, and the addition of new data *did not change the state of that original observation* (i.e. the `bottomRef` was intersecting *and is still intersecting after data load*).

On the left is the initial render (5 elements), and the right is after the initial intersection that triggers the fetch of an additional 10 elements. Note that in either case the final element is well within the viewport.

[image]

---

The question here is:

- Under what conditions would the IntersectionObserver resubmit its assertion that the `bottomRef` reference is intersecting?
- Can I somehow *invalidate* previous events, or otherwise *force* the observer to continuously report its state?
- How can I continuously trigger the IntersectionObserver while the observed element is contained within the client viewport? The design would be that once the parent element reports that no more data is available that the observer be deliberately disarmed.

I tried various incantations of using `clientHeight` and `scrollHeight` on the container element of the `props.children` elements but Chrome was always reporting to me that `clientHeight == scrollHeight`, which seemed wrong to me based on the docs I was reading.

Some other approach here I am not thinking of?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest another approach. Forgive me that I will be using Vue - I hope it will be easier enough to get the idea.
So, imagine that we have a Vue component which must show a list of search results:

```html
<template>
  <div ref="container" class="grow scroll">
    <ProductResult 
      v-for="(item,idx) in results" 
      :key="item._id" 
      v-observe-visibility="visibilityParams" 
      :product="item" 
      :data-last="idx + 1 == results.length ? 'true' : null" 
      @click="showProduct(item)" 
    />
  </div>
</template>
```

How we render each result with the `ProductResult` component is irrelevant for the current discussion.
The important thing is that each result has its own IntersectionObserver instance (through the `v-observe-visibility` Vue directive) with the following parameters (directly used by a `IntersectionObserver` constructor):

```js
computed:
{
      visibilityParams()
      {
        return {
          callback: this.visibilityChanged,
          once: true,
          intersection:
            {
              threshold: 0.1,
            },
        };
      },
}
```

Notice that we instruct the IntersectionObserver's to trigger only **once**. We also mark the last result with `data-last="true"` attribute - you will see how I use this below.
The callback function goes like this:

```js
      visibilityChanged(isVisible, entry)
      {
        if (isVisible && entry.target.dataset.last && this.results.length >= 10) // we assume that each page of results that we fetch from the API contains up to 10 products
        {
          this.pageIndex++;
          this.doSearch();
        }
      },
```

So, if the item enters the viewport (or if it is already visible even on the initial rendering) **AND** it is the last item **AND** we have fetched at least **one full page** of results (i.e. the total number of results **is not** less than one page) - then we fetch the next page of results from the API.
We also use a lifecycle hook in our Vue component called **mounted** (so it is called by Vue when the component is instantiated) to fetch the first page of results:

```js
  mounted()
  {
    this.doSearch();
  },
```

And the actual fetching from the API:

```js
  doSearch()
  {
    // cancel the running search - user is typing faster than the server can perform searching
    // the actual way of cancelling depends on what you use - Fetch API or XHR

    if (this.noMoreResults) return;

    // fetch the data
    // .....

    // after the data was fetched, then
    // if we already have the first page - append these results to the existing ones (a.k.a infinite scroll)
    if (this.pageIndex > 1) this.results = this.results.concat(response.products);
    // otherwise this IS the first page of results
    else this.results = response.products;
    // if the API did not return any new results
    if (response.products.length == 0)
    {
      if (this.pageIndex > 1) this.noMoreResults = true; // then we know that we've shown all possible results
    }
  },
```

---

As a summary - we watch (with an IntersectionObserver) until the last item becomes visible and then we (try to) fetch the next page/group of items. If there are no more items - we use a flag to mark the condition. Once we fetch all items - we receive no more signals from the IntersectionOberver's.

Comment: How is this structurally different from what I have posted above? In React I accomplish a similar feat by attaching a `ref` to a div that is rendered just below the very last `child` ReactNode. And when this div intersects with the viewport the observer callback fetches the next 10 elements. The issue I observed is that when the next 10 elements are fetched, the final element (the div with the `ref`) is _still_ visible in the viewport (as it was before). And so the observer callback does not run again (to fetch another 10 elements). If I were to fetch, say, 100 elements then it works fine.

Comment: The problem comes from the fact that you are inserting the next 10 elements **after** the DIV with the `ref` rather than **before** that DIV. This DIV must always stay the last child of its container. The difference between your approach and mine is that in my code the last "element" is always recognized as **last** because of the corresponding `data-last` attribute - and when I add another group of elements to the screen, the `last` element is changed.

Comment: My code also handles the case when the container can handle (visibly fit) more than 1 page of elements (e.g. 10) - once the first batch is rendered, the last element of the group triggers the IntersectionObserver and another batch is fetched and rendered - until either the last element goes below the fold or there are no more pages to fetch.

Answer (score 0):

It occurred to me that the problem could be solved by adjusting the dependency list of the `useEffect` that creates the `IntersectionObserver`.

The issue's root cause is that the the final element in the list (the one with the `ref` being observed) is *visible in the viewport on initial render*. This triggers the initial intersection callback from the Observer. Upon adding more data to the list the `ref` being observer *remains* visible in the viewport (and so its state has not changed). This means no further callbacks are executed because the visibility of the element is not changing.

But by adding the list of `children` ReactNode elements to the dependency array of the `useEffect` we can create a new observer instance each time a new list of children nodes is passed to the component (and so on each render of the new children list following a fetch of data).

```
const InfiniteScroll = (props: Props) => {
    const bottomRef = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
            if (entries[0].isIntersecting)
                props.next();
        });

        if (bottomRef.current)
            observer.observe(bottomRef.current);

        return () => {
            if (bottomRef.current)
                observer.unobserve(bottomRef.current);
        };
    }, [props.children]);

    return (
        <>
            {props.children}
            {props.hasMore && <div ref={bottomRef}></div>}
        </>
    )
}

export default InfiniteScroll;
```

Perhaps not the most efficient solution, but for the general human-user use-case it seems acceptable, though I am open to alternatives.

Alternatively we could retain the existing IntersectionObserver and create a *new* element to observe on each loop (rather than retaining the same reference created the first time the component is rendered), but I was not quite sure how to do that.